# python code error.(python3.4.4)

Tags: python, file

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\errorword.py",
line 16, in <module>
    read_text()   File "C:\Python34\errorword.py", line 9, in read_text
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)   File "C:\Python34\errorword.py", line 12, in check_profanity
    connection = urllib.urlopen(" http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q="+text_to_check) AttributeError:

'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Comment: show your code in question

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x, you must use

```
urllib.request.urlopen(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> urlopen(...)
```